# Error with simple ClassQueryRq to Quickbooks Web Connector

Tags: soap, quickbooks, qbwc

Here is what my server is sending as a SOAP response to the QB web connector. It's a simple ClassQueryRq. I have triple checked the syntax and XML.. I am really stuck as to why the Web connector is throwing the below error.

Does any see anything I'm missing?

Here is the response that is causing an error.

SOAP Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><sendRequestXMLResponse xmlns="http://developer.intuit.com/"><sendRequestXMLResult>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;?&gt;&lt;?qbxml version=&quot;16.0&quot;?&gt;&lt;QBXML&gt;&lt;QBXMLMsgsRq onError=&quot;continueOnError&quot;&gt;&lt;ClassQueryRq requestID=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&lt;/QBXMLMsgsRq&gt;&lt;/QBXML&gt;</sendRequestXMLResult></sendRequestXMLResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Error: [image]